# Yii Add to Cart functionality

Tags: database, function, yii, cart

I'm a Yii newbie. We have two MVC's in our test app: Apparatus and Order. I should be able to give a function where if a user clicks so, I import the selected row to Order, including the foreign key. It's like a makeshift cart. The problem is, since we are using GII, the CRUD and MODEL are already hard coded and it's confusing whether I should just put something like

```
$db->createCommand('INSERT INTO customer (name) VALUES (:name)', [':name' => 'Qiang',])->execute();
```

Does anybody have advice on how to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

From your question I can see you are newbie to MVC as well. So I strongly recommend you to follow guide in http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.mvc and the fundamentals section.

Don't worry about Gii's auto generated codes. You can go ahead and customize them to achieve your goals.

For your question, There should be a create() function in OrderController if you have used Gii's CRUD generation. So you have to pass the apparatus_id to order controller from add to cart button/link. From there you get the foreign key.